# Execute a correlated subquery for each returned row with MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I'm trying to compute some stats about sport players using MySQL. The database has 3 tables.

The related Rextester: http://rextester.com/SNAL27886

**player**

The list of players.

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | team_id | lastname  |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 | Moubandje |
|  2 |       2 | Rüfli     |
|  3 |       3 | Selnaes   |
|  4 |       1 | Somália   |
|  5 |       4 | Kerbrat   |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

**match**

The list of teams.

```
+----+--------------+--------------+-----+
| id | home_team_id | away_team_id | day |
+----+--------------+--------------+-----+
|  1 |            1 |            2 |   1 |
|  2 |            2 |            1 |   2 |
|  3 |            2 |            3 |   3 |
|  4 |            3 |            4 |   4 |
|  5 |            3 |            5 |   5 |
+----+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

**player_match**

The stats of a player per match.

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+
| player_id | match_id | rating    | substitute | goals |
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+
|         1 |        1 |         6 |          0 |     2 |
|         2 |        2 |         5 |          1 |     0 |
|         1 |       10 |         3 |          0 |     0 |
+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Here is my query to compute various stats about the player (like his number of goals, or his global average rating):

```
SELECT
  p.id AS p_id,
  p.lastname AS lastname,
  p.team_id as team_id,
  AVG(pm.rating) AS avg_rating,
  COUNT(pm.player_id) AS nb_matches,
  SUM(pm.substitute) AS nb_matches_substitute,
  SUM(pm.goals) AS goals,
  (SUM(pm.goals) / COUNT(pm.player_id)) AS goals_per_matches
FROM
  player p
  INNER JOIN player_match pm ON pm.player_id = p.id
  INNER JOIN `match` m ON pm.match_id = m.id AND (m.home_team_id = p.team_id OR m.away_team_id = p.team_id)
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.lastname,
  p.team_id
ORDER BY
  avg_rating DESC, lastname ASC
;
```

I also want to compute the average rating of the player for the last 5 matches of **his team** (if the player has not played a match, his rating must be 0). Then, I want to order the result of the list by this specfic average rating.

Here is my query to retrieve the average rating of a given player for the last 5 games of his team and the ratings for each match as a string:

```
SELECT
  SUM(pm1.rating) / COUNT(m1.id) last_5_matches_rating,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(m1.day, '=', COALESCE(pm1.rating, '~')) ORDER BY m1.day)
FROM
  `match` m1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT m2.id, m2.home_team_id, m2.away_team_id
    FROM `match` m2
    AND (m2.home_team_id=1 OR m2.away_team_id=1)
    ORDER BY m2.day DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) last_5_games ON m1.id = last_5_games.id
  LEFT JOIN player_match pm1 ON m1.id = pm1.match_id AND pm1.player_id=4
```

Here its the result for the player #4 member of the team #1.

Is there a way to execute this last query as a subquery of the previous one and order results by `last_5_matches_rating`?

What I expect is a result with the following columns:

```
| id | lastname | team_id | avg_rating | last_5_matches_rating | nb_matches | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not able to get a query returning the expected results, but I've switched to an alternative and obvious way to do the job.

I've added two computed columns in the player table: `last_five_matches_avg_rating` and `last_five_matches_ratings`.

After every database update, a script is executed: it loops over all the players, execute the second query to retrieve the stats and store those computed stats in the corresponding columns.

Here is this PHP script (it uses Doctrine ORM):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Entity\Player;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class StatsComputer
{
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $manager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $stmt = $manager->getConnection()->prepare(<<<SQL
SELECT
  SUM(pm1.rating) / COUNT(m1.id) last_5_matches_avg_rating,
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(pm1.rating, '0')) ORDER BY m1.day) last_5_matches_ratings
FROM
  `match` m1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT m2.id, m2.home_team_id, m2.away_team_id
    FROM `match` m2
    AND (m2.home_team_id=:team_id OR m2.away_team_id=:team_id)
    ORDER BY m2.day DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) last_5_games ON m1.id = last_5_games.id
  LEFT JOIN player_match pm1 ON m1.id = pm1.match_id AND pm1.player_id=:player_id
SQL
);

        foreach ($this->doctrine->getRepository(Player::class)->findAll() as $player) {
            /**
             * @var $player Player
             */
            $stmt->execute(['team_id' => $player->team->id, 'player_id' => $player->id]);
            $results = $stmt->fetch();

            $player->last5MatchesAvgRating = $results['last_5_matches_avg_rating'];
            $player->last5MatchesRatings = array_map('intval', explode(',', $results['last_5_matches_ratings']));
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

And the updated version of the first query:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS p_id,
  p.lastname AS lastname,
  p.team_id as team_id,
  p.last_5_matches_avg_rating as last_5_matches_avg_rating,
  p.last_5_matches_ratings as last_5_matches_ratings,
  AVG(pm.rating) AS avg_rating,
  COUNT(pm.player_id) AS nb_matches,
  SUM(pm.substitute) AS nb_matches_substitute,
  SUM(pm.goals) AS goals,
  (SUM(pm.goals) / COUNT(pm.player_id)) AS goals_per_matches
FROM
  player p
  INNER JOIN player_match pm ON pm.player_id = p.id
  INNER JOIN `match` m ON pm.match_id = m.id AND (m.home_team_id = p.team_id OR m.away_team_id = p.team_id)
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.lastname,
  p.team_id,
  p.last_5_matches_avg_rating,
  p.last_5_matches_ratings
ORDER BY
  last_5_matches_avg_rating DESC, avg_rating DESC, lastname ASC
;
```

It's not exactly what I wanted initially, but it does the trick (this database has a low number of updates) and it's fast.

I hope it may help someone.